# Efficient way to find all paths between two nodes in a non-cyclical directed graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, network-programming, julia

I want to find all paths between two nodes in a graph. I wrote a recursive function that finds all the paths with help of the depth-first-search algorithm. But for bigger graphs, it is very inefficient, so that i can not use it for my programm.

I am thinking about implementing an **iterative method for my problem**. This will be very time consuming for me. So did anybody know if this would make sense?

Is an iterative way more efficient in this case? Or is it possible to optimize my recursive method?

My current function:

```
function RecDFS(g::GenericGraph, visited)
    nodes = out_neighbors(visited[length(visited)], g) 

    for i in nodes
    if in(i,visited)
        continue
    end

    if i.label == "End"
        push!(visited,i)
        println(visited) # print every path from the first node in visited to the node with the label End
        pop!(visited)
        break
    end

    # continue recursive..
    for i in nodes
        if (in(i, visited) || i.label == "End")
            continue
        end
        push!(visited,i)
        depthFirstSearchAllI(g, visited)
        pop!(visited)
    end
end
```

Comment: what was the point of the graph being DAG?

Comment: There should be no significant difference
between a recursive and an iterative approach:
they will examine the same paths.
You can simplify your code: you do not need two loops
(and there is a missing `end`, probably in the middle);
you do not need to check `in(i,visited)`
if you are sure your graph is acyclic (and checking can be time-consuming).
What is the size of the graph?
Do you have an idea of the number of paths that should be returned?
It can be exponential in the size of the graph...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thoughts i have found a good solution for my problem. Take a look at this example code:

```
function RecDFS(g::GenericGraph, visited)
   nodes = out_neighbors(visited[length(visited)], g) 
   if(checkPath(visited))
       for i in nodes
           if in(i,visited)
              continue
           end

           if i.label == "End"
               push!(visited,i)
               println(visited) # print every path from the first node in visited to the node with the label End
               pop!(visited)
               break
           end
        end

   # continue recursive..
       for i in nodes
           if (in(i, visited) || i.label == "End")
               continue
           end
           push!(visited,i)
           depthFirstSearchAllI(g, visited)
           pop!(visited)
       end
   end
end
```

All in all i have just added an additional if-statement. The function `checkPath(visited)` returns true, if the path is valid until now. If the path (or piece of path) is not valid, the function ends.

For my specific problem, this is a very good solution. It was 100 times faster in my test run and needs only 15 seconds for my biggest problem instance with 500 nodes and 16000 edges.

Thank you very much Ashkan Kzme and Rob for your help.

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem. Can you please let me know what the function depthFirstSearchAllI does?

Comment: long time ago... I think it is a copy-paste error and must be a recursive call like: RecDFS(g, visited) isntead of depthFirstSearchAllI

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are trying to solve is actually an NP-hard problem, which means there is no polynomial time algorithm for it, yet!

So you can maybe find some optimizations for your problem, but you cannot have it run fast enough!

As in optimizations, you can do the following. First of all you mentioned in your question topic that your input is a DAG graph, and DAGs by definition have the following property:

There are no paths between two nodes in two different connected parts of DAG.

so if you have a list of what nodes are in which connected piece of the DAG ( this is achievable in polynomial time ), you can easily cross out a lot of hopeless combinations.

As in making your program iterative, you can easily use a stack instead. Just replace every recursive call with a stack.push(node) and put the traverse part of your code inside a while(stack is not empty), and just pop the nodes one by one unless there are none. That should do it.

Comment: I think you are right and i think, that an iterative way could be an optimization for my problem. For example it is easier to detect potential paths that are not useful. So maybe i could reduce the number of possible combinations...

Comment: Your edits sounds very usefull, thank you! In the moment i try a further recursive solution, if it works i will post it. Otherwise i am goinig to take into account your edits and try it this way.

Comment: @team17 you're welcome. on a side note, I think if you want to perform optimizations on your code, its always better to have it the non-recursive way.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the vertices in your DAG, to get `[v0, v1, ... , vn]`. Suppose your start node is `vs`, your destination `vt`. (If `s > t` then there are no paths)

Then, for each `i` in  `s+1 .. t` calculate the paths `P(i)` from `vs` to `vi` as follows:

- If there's an edge `vs -> vi`, that's one path (of length 1)
- Find all `j` such that `s < j < i` and there's an edge `vj -> vi`. Add all paths obtained by taking paths from `P(j)` and appending the edge `vj -> vi`
- Note. for a given `i` there's no guarantee that there are any paths at all from `vs` to `vi`

As already commented, there can be exponentially many paths, thus outputting all paths can't in general be done in less than exponential time. However, you can calculate the number of paths in linear time using this approach.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. There can be any number of topological sorts for a dag. So operating on only one does not give us all paths! for your idea, you need to find all topological sorts of a dag.

Comment: @Ashkan. There are many topological sorts, but any one of them can be used to find all paths, it doesn't matter which you choose. In fact the sort is not strictly necessary, but it's just a convenient way of ordering the vertices to consider, and ruling out all vertices beyond `t` (as no edge or path can go backwards with respect to the sort).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue for depth first search, which saves the nodes you've just passed by.

Comment: Yes, in my orginal function i do so. Instead of printing the vertices i store them in Arrays